# Java SMTP send email with authentication but without seeing the password

Tags: java, authentication, smtp, passwords

I want to send an email using our Exchange server and I must use authentication to send it to an email address which is not in our domain. They do not want to give me the password because of security issues.

My question is: Can I use authentication without seeing the password that I need?

Comment: Can you clarify: The password for what? (And who are _They_?)

Comment: The password for logging the user in. Apparently i cannot send emails outside our domain at our company without using authentication. They are people who are responsible for the exchange server and intern IT.